# How do I make the sound from a tennis ball hitting the floor softer?

Tags: everyday-life, projectile, elasticity

I enjoy practicing cricket bowling at my house, much to the dismay of my brother, as it results a normal tennis ball making a high pitched 'thud' when bouncing off of the floor. How could I reduce the sound made when hitting the floor? Could something like tape help?

Comment: Maybe try wetting the ball ?

Comment: Anything that you do to the ball or floor to change the sound is going to affect the behaviour of the ball and not reflect a ball in actual play.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably cover the floor on a material with lower stiffness like a foam.